# Looping through dataframe to extract substrings that match dictionary

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, substring

I'm trying to loop through a column in a dataframe, and create a new column using substrings from the looped column if it contains a value in a dictionary.  More specifically, if the individual row in the column of addresses contains a state in the dictionary of state names and abbreviations, then append the state abbreviation to a list that will become the new column.

The below code works for full matches, but isn't scanning the rows for substrings:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame((['Austin, Texas',
               'Texas',
               'Seattle, Washington',
               ',,, Texas',
               'Olympia, WA']), columns = ['Place'])

states = {'Texas': 'TX',
      'Washington': 'WA'}

place = df['Place']

results = []

for x in place:
    if x in states:
        results.append(x)
    else:
        results.append(None)

df['State'] = results
df
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested conditional list comprehension will do the trick. You need to split on the commas and use strip to remove white space.

Also, New York, New York (city, state) could cause a problem, so I left the results in a list.

```
df['results'] = [[state.strip() for state in cell.split(',') 
                  if state.strip() in states] 
                 for cell in df.Place]

df['results2'] = df.results.apply(lambda s: s[-1] if s else '')

>>> df
                 Place       results    results2
0        Austin, Texas       [Texas]       Texas
1                Texas       [Texas]       Texas
2  Seattle, Washington  [Washington]  Washington
3            ,,, Texas       [Texas]       Texas
4          Olympia, WA            []
```

Comment: I forgot to ask, how would you return a non-list with this?  I don't think I have New York, New York in my data, so it shouldn't be a problem for me.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but I'm getting a "name 'cell' is not defined" error?  A quick google search didn't seem to pull up anything?